# Disable Reminder using objective c

Tags: objective-c, reminders

I am developing an app for medicine reminder. The user inserts the medicine name and time from date picker and I create a reminder for each one.

My question: how I can delete a reminder when the user wants to edit the medicine time for any kind of medicine?

This is my code to save a reminder:

```
 // Get the current date

    NSDate *pickerDate = [datePicker date];
   // Break the date up into components
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )      fromDate:pickerDate];

    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) fromDate:pickerDate];

    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];

    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];

    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];

    [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];

//  // Notification will fire in one minute

    [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];

[dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];

    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
if([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])

{
    // iOS 6 and later

    // asks user to allow application to use his device calendar

    [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeReminder completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)

     {
        if (granted)
        {
            EKReminder *reminder = [EKReminder reminderWithEventStore:eventStore];

             reminder.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"وقت الدواء"] ;

             reminder.calendar = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewReminders];

            // NSDate *date = itemDate;

             EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:itemDate];
             [reminder addAlarm:alarm];
             [EventIDArray addObject:alarm];

             NSError *error = nil;
             [eventStore saveReminder:reminder commit:YES error:&error];

             if(error)

                 NSLog(@"unable to Reminder!: Error= %@", error);
        }

     }];

}

// iOS < 6

else
```

{
       EKReminder *reminder = [EKReminder reminderWithEventStore:eventStore];

```
    reminder.title = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"وقت الدواء"] ;

    reminder.calendar = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewReminders];

    NSDate *date = itemDate;

    EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:date];

    [reminder addAlarm:alarm];
    [EventIDArray addObject:alarm];
    NSError *error = nil;

    [eventStore saveReminder:reminder commit:YES error:&error];

    if(error)

        NSLog(@"unable to Reminder!: Error= %@", error);
```

I use remove reminder but the reminder still active.

```
[eventStore removeReminder:[EventIDArray objectAtIndex:row] commit:YES error:&error];
```

Thank you, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

To effectively cancel a reminder (EKReminder), you should set the completed property to YES.

This will automatically set completionDate for that EKReminder to the current date.

[Apple API Documentation for EKReminder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKReminderClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011849-CH1-SW7)

As mentioned in the above documentation, you can simply set the property to YES to cancel a reminder.

For you I imagine that would look something like this:

```
(EKReminder *)[EventIDArray objectAtIndex:row].completed = YES;
```

Assuming that the object returned from:

```
[EventIDArray objectAtIndex:row]
```

is the EKReminder object instance you wish to cancel.

Comment: Thank u John Woods for response, but what do you mean by set the completed property to YES? which property?

Comment: Hi Fadia, the EKReminder class itself has a property called 'completed', you need to set this to 'YES' to cancel a given reminder. I have updated the answer. Let me know if you have any more questions on this.

Comment: Hi John, if u notes I add alarm to EventIDArray, what do u see is this correct or I should add itemDate? when I use [EventIDArray objectAtIndex:row].completed = YES; I have this error: Property 'completed' not found on object of type 'id', and when I put all reminders are cancelled  EKReminder *reminder = [EKReminder reminderWithEventStore:eventStore];
        reminder.completed=YES;

Comment: Hi Fadia, As mentioned by Mihir, you should cast the id object to an EKReminder. I have updated my answer - apologies for the inaccuracy, I don't have XCode to hand.

Comment: Thank u John and Mihir, after I cast the object the same error  Property 'completed' not found on object of type 'id'

Comment: It sounds as though you are not casting correctly, can you post your code as it currently is and also post a complete copy of the compiler error?

Comment: This is the code for turn off reminder:                    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
         NSError *error = nil;
        [eventStore removeReminder:[EventIDArray objectAtIndex:row] commit:YES error:&error];
        (EKReminder *)[EventIDArray objectAtIndex:row].completed = YES; and the error : Property 'completed' not found on object of type 'id'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44168/discussion-between-john-woods-and-fadia-jaradat)

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the object returned from the array like this.

```
(EKReminder *)[EventIDArray objectAtIndex:row].completed = YES;
```